# Save image to the File Directory

Tags: ios, swift, nsfilemanager

I am trying to save images using the File Directory but I am unable to without an error saying

> No Such Folder.

Here's my code, I am not sure where I am going wrong

```
// Write image to directory
func writeImageToPath(_ path: String, image: UIImage) {
    print("Write image to directory")

    // get the documents directory url
    let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]

    let folderURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("upload")

    if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: folderURL.path) {
        do {
            try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: folderURL.path, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
        }
        catch {}
    }

    let fileURL = folderURL.appendingPathComponent(path)
    let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.9)
    do {
        try data!.write(to: fileURL)
    }
    catch {}

}

// load image from directory
func loadImageFromPath(_ path: String) -> UIImage? {

    let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]

    let folderURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("upload")

    let fileURL = folderURL.appendingPathComponent(path)

    if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileURL.path) {
        //Get Image And upload in server
        print("fileURL.path \(fileURL.path)")

        do{
            let data = try Data.init(contentsOf: fileURL)
            let image = UIImage(data: data)
            return image
        }catch{
            print("error getting image")
        }
    } else {
        print("No image in directory")
    }

    return nil
}
```

How can I correctly save and load images from the directory ?

Comment: Instead of providing the answer I would like to tell you the mistake you're making. First you will have to create the directory before writing the `imageData`. Second you need to use extensions `.jpg, .png` for image name in full path.

Answer (score 3):

Roe,

I have been following below snippet of code in most of the projects:

To save image in folder, use below function:

```
func addImageInFolder(image : UIImage,filename:String){
    let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
    let folderURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("upload")
    if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: folderURL.path) {
        do {
            try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: folderURL.path, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
        }
        catch {}
    }
    let fileURL = folderURL.appendingPathComponent(filename)
    let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.9)
    do {
        try data!.write(to: fileURL)
    }
    catch {}
}
```

Use below function to remove image from stored folder:

```
let fileURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("upload/\(filename ?? "")")

            if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileURL.absoluteString){
                do{
                    try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: fileURL)
                }catch{
                    print("\(sigStr ?? "") delete file delete error")
                }

            }
```

To Get image from folder:

```
let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
                //TODO: -Get dateTime For get image URL-
                let fileURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("upload/\(fileName)")
                if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileURL.path) {
                    //Get Image And upload in server
                    print("fileURL.path \(fileURL.path)")

                    do{
                        let data = try Data.init(contentsOf: fileURL)
                        imageView.image = UIImage(data: data)
                    }catch{

                    }
                }
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I no longer get any errors when saving the image, however when loading I do not get any results. I have updated my question with my load function, how can I load the image and return it  ? Thank you for your help

Comment: @A.Roe I have updated my answer. Hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you, but for some reason when retrieving the image the file isn't found, I have updated my code in my question and you can see where the console prints         print("No image in directory"), any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4.2**

```
func saveAndGetImageFromDirectory(_ data: Data, name: String, completionHandler: @escaping (URL?)->()) {
        let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
        var imageURL:URL!

        imageURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent(name)

        do {
            try data.write(to: imageURL)

            var documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
            documentsPath = documentsPath + "/\(name)"
            completionHandler(URL.init(fileURLWithPath: documentsPath))
        } catch let error {
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

Comment: `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains` is outdated and *objective-c-ish*. And never build paths with `+` and concatenating strings

Answer (score -2):

```
Swift 4:
try this code maybe it will helps you.
//saving image in directory and
            let fileManager = FileManager.default
            //get the image path
            let imagePath = (NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString).appendingPathComponent(imageName)
            //get the image we took from gallery
            let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage
            //get the PNG data for this image
            let data = image!.pngData()
            //store it in the document directory
            fileManager.createFile(atPath: imagePath as String, contents: data, attributes: nil)
```

Comment: Don't use `(NS)String` to build paths. `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains` is outdated. Use the URL related API of FileManager and methods like `appendingPathComponent()` have been moved to  `URL`.